# Python and selenium in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, selenium

Is there an operative system for raspberry pi where I can install python, xvfb and selenium so that I can run a python script using selenium and pyvirtualdisplay??

If there are some operative systems that fit these characteristcs, which one would be the fastest to boot and to be ready for use once booted??

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here - especially with respect to an expected amount of own research.

Answer (score 1):

Python is available on many platforms as is selenium. xvfb should run on most Unix-like OS. So my guess would be that any reasonable Linux distribution available for the Pi should do fine.

With respect to fast booting I recommend looking into some of the already existing answers, e.g.:

- [How do I improve Raspberry Pi Boot Up Time?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19358/how-do-i-improve-raspberry-pi-boot-up-time)
- [How to improve boot time for Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14763/how-to-improve-boot-time-for-raspberry-pi)